# Coredata: Backup and Restore a database file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I've searched and have not found much regarding creating a backup and restoring a database file, so I am hoping someone smarter than me can point me in the right direction.

This is on OSX.

I successfully created a backup, restoring has been the main issue. However I'm almost there, I've successfully restore a database file BUT I need to restart the app for it to work.

Restore method:

```
 [_managedObjectContext reset];
 NSPersistentStore *currentStore = self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.lastObject;
 [_persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:currentStore error:&error];
 NSFileManager *filemanager;
 filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 if ([filemanager fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]) {
    //If the file exist, remove file  
    if ([filemanager removeItemAtURL:url error:&error]) {}
 }
 [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:urlbackup options:nil error:&error];
 currentStore = self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.lastObject;

 [_persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:currentStore toURL:url options:options withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];
```

That all works, **IF** I restart the app. How can I get it to work without restarting the app? It appears I need to reload all the data and refresh the view.

I've tried the following after without success:

```
 [arrayController rearrangeObjects];
 [tableView reloadData];
```

Again, if I restart the app everything is fine, the backup file is restored. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ littleDrummerBoy : Did you get any solution ? I am having same situation.

Comment: @Bucket : Sorry for the late comment, been traveling a lot lately. Is there a way to send private message on here? Let me know if you still need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put the code that creates the Core Data stack somewhere reusable, which means not in the app delegate if that's where it currently is. You should also destroy the views, or at least the view controllers references to any currently existing managed objects, contexts, etc.

Now, once that's done, the owner of the context can destroy it, the persistent store and the model, and then re-run the stack creation code. After that you can recreate your view (or pass the new context / managed object to the VC).

It's simply about reorganising your code so it's reusable and ensuring that you don't leave any old references to invalidated objects.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you're saying, but might take a bit to implement. On this project I am using XCodes template and decided to leave all the coredata stuff in the app delegate. The rest of the code is in a main controller, and I don't currently have a separate VC either. Looks like a bit of recoding in order to rearrange as you suggested.

Comment: That's what I needed - thanks. Moved the Core Data stack to my main controller. In restore method, destroyed stack, replaced files with backups, recreated stack and reestablished links to context.